# debian apt broken after mixin lenny sid and apt-get update / upgrade

Tags: debian, apt

I ran an `apt-get update` / `upgrade` on a server I don't know before. The `apt-get update` hadn't been done since a long time (a year I guess..).

The second mistake is that I didn't check `/etc/apt/sources.list` before running the upgrade: unfortunately there was a reference to the sid repository! (this is a prod server serving apache / PHP apps..)

I've removed the sid reference and changed it to squeeze: now my sources list is (OK, this is a mess but I'm afraid to break this production server so any good advice is welcome.)

```
deb    ftp://mirror.hetzner.de/debian/packages  lenny          main contrib non-free
deb    ftp://mirror.hetzner.de/debian/security  lenny/updates  main contrib non-free

deb     http://ftp.uni-bayreuth.de/linux/Debian/debian/  lenny  main non-free contrib
deb-src http://ftp.uni-bayreuth.de/linux/Debian/debian/  lenny  main non-free contrib

deb     http://security.debian.org/  lenny/updates  main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/  lenny/updates  main contrib non-free

deb     ftp://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian squeeze main
deb-src     ftp://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian squeeze main
```

Now I cant complete the upgrade process.

```
apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 97 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up linux-image-2.6.26-2-amd64 (2.6.26-29) ...
Running depmod.
Failed to find suitable ramdisk generation tool for kernel version 
2.6.26-2-amd64 on running kernel 2.6.26-2-amd64 in mkinitramfs-kpkg mkinitrd.yaird
dpkg: error processing linux-image-2.6.26-2-amd64 (--configure):
 subprocess post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-2.6.26-2-amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've made a lot of search on Google and so on for this issue and never found a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood this right, you can try to download `initramfs-tools` .deb file and install it with `dpkg`. Then re-run `apt-get install -f`.